# Parameter issue with plink and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssh, plink

I am trying to ssh into a switch using plink, but I keep getting errors with my parameters.

```
$plink = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe'
$switch = "172.20.19.50"
$commands = "c:\scripts\cmd.txt"
$username = Read-Host "User name"
$pw =  Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$plink -l $username -pw $pw -m $commands -ssh $switch﻿
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:7 char:8

Unexpected token 'l' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:9

Unexpected token 'username' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:11

Unexpected token '-pw' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:21

Unexpected token 'pw' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:25

Unexpected token '-m' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:29

Unexpected token 'commands' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:32

Unexpected token '-ssh' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:42

Unexpected token 'switch' in expression or statement.
At line:7 char:47
```

My parameters are correct as far as I can see, any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell powershell that you're running a command with parameters, otherwise it doesn't know how to interpret your list of arguments, to get this working, you can simply add the `&` symbol before your command:

```
& $plink -l $username -pw $pw -m $commands -ssh $switch﻿
```